# Deleting blanks from the beginning of a String

Tags: java, string

I've got a String:

`str ="     4    3"` ,

I need to remove the blanks only before the '4' and not between 4 and 3.

Here's the code i wrote to get this : "f4_***3" .But it gives "4***_3".

```
private static String getFielName(String fieldName) {
    String formattedName;

    //here i need to delete the blanks before the '4'
    formattedName = Character.isDigit(fieldName.charAt(0)) ? "f" + fieldName : fieldName;
    return formattedName.trim().replace(' ', '_').replace(":", "").replace("°", "");
}
```

Comment: Are you not allowed to use utility methods such as `trim()` ?

Comment: You're already using trim() in there ....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about

```
str = str.trim();
```

(see [`trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29))

Note that this will remove both leading *and* trailing spaces. If you only want to remove the leading ones, you can try

```
str = str.replaceFirst("^\\s+", "");
```

(see [`replaceFirst()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29))

Comment: Not sure this deserves its upvotes since OP is already using trim, only in the wrong place.

Comment: @Keyser Indeed, good thing that's not the only component of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This will remove leading blanks:

```
str = str.replaceAll("^\\s+", "");
```

---

You could use `str.trim()`, but that removes *trailing* blanks too, and your question does not make it clear if that's OK or not.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your code is not working as expected is that you are checking whether the first character is a digit *before* you remove the leading blanks with `trim()`.  You just need to rearrange your code a little bit.

```
private static String getFielName(String fieldName) {
    String formattedName = fieldname.trim();
    formattedName = Character.isDigit(formattedName.charAt(0)) ? 
                                      "f" + formattedName : formattedName ;
    return formattedName.replace(' ', '_').replace(":", "").replace("°", "");
}
```

Note that if you only want to remove leading blanks but keep trailing blanks (I suspect you don't), then you can use `replaceFirst()` instead of `trim()` like others have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

```
trim()
```

will return your string without spaces in the start and ends.

Ex:

```
String s =" te st ";
s =s.trim(); //will become "te st"
```